# Why Cursor points to its latest position being set in anonymous class

Tags: android

Can you guys explain why `cursor` reference being passed for each row as different instance finally comes to `mDBHelper.updateFavorites()` pointing to its latest position. Because I'm expecting the `cursor` passed to `onClick()` method is where actually `Cursor c` is pointing at the moment of this object passing, but this is not the case. Thank you very much.

```
@Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row;
            final Cursor cursor = c; // This is different for each row in list view
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            this.defaultDrawable = (Drawable) row.getBackground();
            final CheckBox mStar = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.star);
            mStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mStar.isChecked()) {
                        mDbHelper.updateFavorite(cursor, 1); // Here I'm expecting to have the cursor pointing exactly where Cursor c (which is passed to newView() method) is pointing right now.
                    } else {
                        mDbHelper.updateFavorite(cursor, 0); // The same here
                    }
                }
            });

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(row);

            row.setTag(holder);

            return (row);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you are not making any copies of the cursor. So actually, that is just a reference to the only one cursor.

So if your are assigning it in some loop, moving each time the initial reference to the net position - all your cursors will be moved also.

Is that how it happen in your case?

Good luck

Comment: Yeah, it's how it happens in my case indeed. Where should I create a copy, in the anonymous class?

Comment: Actually, I think Cursor is too bounded to underlying data, so there is either impossible, or unreasonable to make such copies.
I will suggest you to read-out your cursor first, and than pass different rows to different users in other structures. Either Maps or DataHolders